# Giving Formula For Recursion given a1 and a2

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give a closed formula in terms of $n$ for: $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1$.

In class, we learned how to give a closed formula given $a_0$ and $a_1$, but not for $a_1$ and $a_2$. Please show me the right way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Let $a_i=b_{i-1}$ to reduce the problem to the previously solved one

Comment: Sorry, but what would the formula look like then?

Comment: What I found is that $a_{2n} = \frac {3 \cdot 9^{n-1} - 1} {2}$ and $a_{2n-1} = \frac {9^{n-1} + 1} {2},$ for all $n \in \Bbb N.$

Answer (score 0):

Find $a_n$ for small n

$$a_3=5$$
$$a_4=13$$
$$a_5=41$$
$$a_5=121$$

which is given by
$$a_n={3^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1} \over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=t^n$ in the relation to get
$$t^2-2t-3=0 \implies t=3, -1 \implies a_n=C_1 3^n+ C_2 (-1)^n$$
Further $$a_1=1=a_2 \implies 3C_1-C_2=1, 9C_1+c_2=1 \implies C_1=1/6,~ C_2=-1/2$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1$. Let $a_i=b_{i-1}$.

Then you want to solve $b_{n-1}=2b_{n-2}+3b_{n-3}$, $b_0=1$, $b_1=1$.

This is the same as $b_n=2b_{n-1}+3b_{n-3}$, $b_0=1$, $b_1=1$.

I presume you learned in class that the solution to this is $b_n=\frac123^{n}+\frac12(-1)^{n}$,

so $a_n=b_{n-1}=\frac123^{n-1}+\frac12(-1)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for any $n \in \Bbb N$ $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{2n} \\ a_{2n-1} \end{pmatrix} = {\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} a_2 \\ a_1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and that the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ is diagonalizable.

So $${\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}}^{n-1} = P {\begin{pmatrix} 9 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}^{n-1} P^{-1}$$ where $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a matrix consisting of column vectors which are respectively the eigenvectors of $$\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $9$ and $1.$ Can you finish it from here?